# Signature of a bilinear form in the space of $2 \times 2$ Hermitian matrices

Tags: quadratic-forms

We have a bilinear form,

$$\langle A, A' \rangle = \det(A+A') - \det A - \det A'$$

on the real vector space of Hermitian $2\times 2$ matrices.

If I have a basis of the space, I would calculate the norms of the basis vectors, but here we don't. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you say that it is bilinear?

Comment: @ancientmathematician One can compute it by using the identity $\det(A+B) = \det(A) +\det(B) +tr(A^*B)$

Comment: Of course, sorry, half-asleep. The space is surely four dimensional with basis , $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ so why not calculate?

Comment: @ancientmathematician the result beeing $(3+, 1-)$, i.e. a minkovskian space (space-time metrics)

Comment: Related : see some interesting answers and comments in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1642024

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order to attract more people. I have changed as well the tag ("abstract algebra" is for structures like groups, rings, fields)

Comment: Relate as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/405276